# How to fix unknown table for a table that is in the database?

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

> Error 1051: Unknown Table 'employee'

This is my code:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`u24290718`@`%` PROCEDURE `eval5_get_charter_details_by_pilot_date`(in fromdate DATE, todate DATE, pilotname VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

    if (pilotname = 'all')
    THEN
        SELECT aviaco.pilot.*, aviaco.employee.*

        FROM aviaco.pilot

        JOIN aviaco.employee AS emp on aviaco.pilot.EMP_NUM = aviaco.employee.EMP_NUM;

    ELSE
        SELECT aviaco.pilot.*, aviaco.employee.*

        FROM aviaco.pilot

        JOIN aviaco.employee AS emp on aviaco.pilot.EMP_NUM = aviaco.employee.EMP_NUM

        WHERE aviaco.pilot.PIL_MED_DATE = fromdate & aviaco.pilot.PIL_PT135_DATE = todate;
    END IF;
END
```

So the problem is that I keep getting unknown table `employee`. I am using a database on the university server and the employee table is there! I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is aviaco? the schema? when removing it does it still throws the same error?

Comment: I'm not sure about mysql, but it looks like you've assigned an alias to aviaco.employee ("AS emp") so when referencing its fields elsewhere in the query, you may need to use, e.g. emp.EMP_NUM and emp.* rather than aviaco.employee.EMP_NUM, aviaco.employee.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your issue:

```
aviaco.employee AS emp
```

so your query (not your database) now knows your `employee` table as `emp`. This means you should point to it as such, so for instance (there might be more places!), you can't do this

```
SELECT aviaco.pilot.*, aviaco.employee.*
```

but should do

```
SELECT aviaco.pilot.*, emp.*
```

and in the join it should be `emp.EMP_NUM` etc.